# Get UTF-8 encoded string from byte[]

Tags: go

I'm looking to convert a slice  of bytes `[]byte` into an UTF-8 `string`.

I want to write a function like that :

```
func bytesToUTF8string(bytes []byte)(string){

  // Take the slice of bytes and encode it to UTF-8 string
  // return the UTF-8 string

}
```

What is the most efficient way to perform this

EDIT :

Specifically I want to convert the output of crypto.rsa.EncryptPKCS1v15 or the output of SignPKCS1v15 to an UTF-8 encoded string.

How can I do it ?

Comment: If the slice of bytes is already in UTF-8, that'd just be `string(bytes)`.

Comment: What is the encoding of the []byte?  If it's already UTF-8, then use the conversion as suggested in the previous comment.

Comment: @CeriseLimón  is there a way to programmatically detect the encoding of the slice of bytes ? for instance how to know which encoding is the return type of https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rsa/#EncryptPKCS1v15 ?

Comment: EncryptPKCS1v15, like most encryption algorithms, yields random bytes, not displayable strings. You have to encode the output to display it. base64 encoding is a popular choice.

Comment: Hex encoding is another popular choice.  @Mald edit the question to describe your actual problem: How to convert output from EncryptPKCS1v15 to UTF-8 string?

Comment: You probably need something in [crypto/x509](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/).

Answer (score 1):

```
func bytesToUTF8string(bytes []byte) string {
    return string(bytes)
}
```

It's such a common, simple operation that it's arguably not worth wrapping in a function. Unless, of course, you need to translate the from a different source encoding, then it's an entirely different issue, with which [the `golang.org/x/text/encoding` package](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/encoding) might help

Comment: Will it work with the return of https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rsa/#EncryptPKCS1v15 ?

Comment: @Mald that function does not return a UTF-8 encoded string, you probably want to use Base64 or hexadecimal encoding if you're trying to serialize encrypted data.